# Clicking asp ImageButton returning me back to top of page: Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to allow users to edit information on a page with a onclick edit button

the page reloads and the page is taken back to the top, each time the button is clicked, it seems to be a huge inconvenience to the user

```
  <% Page directives ... MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" .. %>
```

with my page tag at the top, but its still jumping back to the top any suggestions?

I have tried putting it in the webconfig

```
   <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" >
```

i have tried putting an asp:Page tag on the page too

```
   <asp:Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" .... />
```

and still puts the position at the top of the page on reload.

Comment: http://justgeeks.blogspot.fr/2009/04/keep-scroll-position-on-aspnet-page.html or you can use javascript http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/156.aspx

Comment: use javascript to do this type of stuf....

Comment: You write this code in Page directive? Try to use it maintainScrollPositionOnPostback (case sensitive)

Comment: @jacek yes i put it in my directive, ill try lowercase m

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your web.config. It should be your answer

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True">
```

Comment: i just tried 3 different things, what you said about the webconfig.. and i added a Maintain in the page directives and also did